# loop find pattern in map - groovy

Tags: groovy

I want to loop through a map so if regex condition/pattern is met I will put the value into another map, else I will put in the map {trigger-all=true}.

This is what I got so far :

```
def patternsFunc = [
        /(?s).*vee\/.*/  : "vee",
        /(?s).*$HelmServicesPath\/vee\/.*/  : "vee",
        /(?s).*rest\/.*/ : "rest",
        /(?s).*$HelmServicesPath\/rest\/.*/  : "rest",
        /(?s).*service\/.*/ : "service",
        /(?s).*$HelmServicesPath\/service\/.*/  : "service",

]



patternsFunc.find { pattern, cname ->
    if (file.find(pattern)) {
        triggermap."trigger-${cname}" = true
        assert triggermap."trigger-${cname}"
        return true //found
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

But there are 2 problems with this code:

1. the loop here going through every item on the patternsFunc map, so everything I put inside the "else" will happen whenever any of the conditions aren't met for every Item and not on the entire maps I need.
2. How do I put all values from the array to the map inside the "else"?

What I really need to achieve is in case no conditions are met, This will be the content of the map:  **{trigger-all=true}**.

And when a condition(let's say "vee" and "rest") is met, This will be the content of the map:  **{trigger-rest=true,trigger-vee=true}**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, `find`
finds the first result, but you want to find all, so use `findAll`.
Next don't mix side-effects into `find` or alike.  Do the "finding"
first, then deal with the results.  In this case, you want to build a
map from all the results.  Use `collectEntries` for that.

And finally
you want a fallback, if nothing is found.  So you can use the elvis
operator `?:` to provide an alternative, if the resulting map is empty.

E.g.

```
def patterns = [
        (/(?s).*service\/.*/): "service",
]
def file = '/service/'

def triggerMap = patterns.findAll{  // find relevant map entries
        file.find(it.key) 
    }.collectEntries{ // build your map
        ["trigger-${it.value}", true] 
    } ?: ["trigger-all": true] // provide a fallback
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively to what [cfrick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3181392/cfrick) suggested, you can use `inject` method with an empty map as the initial value. That way you can iterate over all patterns, add entries if the pattern is found, and in the end, you can return `["trigger-all": true]` map if no pattern was found.

Below you can find an example that tests 3 different file paths.

```groovy
def patternsFunc = [
    /(?s).*vee\/.*/  : "vee",
    /(?s).*rest\/.*/ : "rest",
    /(?s).*service\/.*/ : "service"
]

def files = [
    "/tmp",
    "/tmp/vee/1",
    "/tmp/vee/rest/1"
]

files.each { file ->
    def result = patternsFunc.inject([:]) { map, pattern, cname ->
        file.find(pattern) ? map + ["trigger-$cname": true] : map
    } ?: ["trigger-all": true]

    println "Result for $file: $result"
}
```